# .gitignore directory/wildcard unexpected behaviour

Tags: git, directory, wildcard, gitignore

Folder structure of the git project:

```
.git/
    <some git stuff>
.gitignore
level1/
    level2/
        file1
        file2
```

The files `.gitignore`, `file1`, and `file2` are all empty.
I run `git add .gitignore` and `git commit -m "create empty .gitignore"`.

If the `.gitignore` is emtpy, `git add -A` followed by `git status` outputs (as expected):

```
new file: level1/level2/file1
new file: level1/level2/file2
```

So, I `git reset` to begin testing the outcome of changes to the `.gitignore` (assume I do this between each of the following changes to the `.gitignore`)

If the `.gitignore` contains either `level1`, `level1/`, `level1/*`, `level2`, or `level2/`, then `git add -A` followed by `git status` outputs (as expected):

```
modified: .gitignore
```

However, if the `.gitignore` contains `level2/*`, then `git add -A` followed by `git status` outputs:

```
modified: .gitignore
new file: level1/level2/file1
new file: level1/level2/file2
```

Why doesn't `level2/*` have the same effect as `level2/` in this case?  Also, while `level2/*` **doesn't** do what I want, `**/level2/*` **does**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [gitignore documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore):

> 1) If the pattern ends with a slash, it would only find a match with a directory.
>
> 2) If the pattern does not contain a slash /, Git treats it as a shell glob pattern and checks for a match against the pathname relative to the location of the .gitignore file (relative to the toplevel of the work tree if not from a .gitignore file).
>
> 3) Otherwise, Git treats the pattern as a shell glob suitable for consumption by fnmatch(3) with the FNM_PATHNAME flag: wildcards in the pattern will not match a / in the pathname. For example, "Documentation/*.html" matches "Documentation/git.html" but not "Documentation/ppc/ppc.html" or "tools/perf/Documentation/perf.html".

The pattern `level2/*` falls into the third case. Since there is no directory `level2` at the root of the project, git doesn't ignore the files in `level1/level2/`.

That's why `**/level2/*` does work, and also why `level2/` and `level2` work.